# Lock screen vs Signing out

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, user-accounts

On the registry level, what are the differences between locking a user session and signing out from a user session?

Aprecciate your help.

Comment: Registry isn't involved at all.

Comment: When you lock program and applications are still on and running but when sign out all program & app will close.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to know before:

- Lock: It will lock the computer, but all the user's program will keep running. Lock can be triggered with <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> > Lock. (Group policy can control what options appear in that menu).
- Disconnect session: It is simillar to lock, will lock the computer and keep User programs running and let other users log in using Remote desktop or physically. It is similar to Switch User when done physically.
- Log out: Close all programs of the user and log out. It is different from disconnecting session, because this will not allow users to connect session from Remote dekstop, only physically another user will log in. Though services and scheduled tasks will continue to run, and any program can run as services or scheduled tasks. This will also let other users connect to this account through RDP or physically.
- Turn off/Shut down: Will close all running programs of current user, if another user is logged in then prompt to turn them off also. Then the computer will switched off and offline.
- Power off (**!!DANGER!!**): Cutting down the power supply when computer is active. It is dangerous, you will lose your unsaved data or files may get corrupted.

Here the main differences between Lock and Log off is:

- Lock keeps user programs running but log off closes them all. But still services and scheduled tasks will continue as is, though you log off, and any program can run in form of them.
- AFAIK No registry involvement will take place.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can Enable Windows 10 Auto Lock Using the Registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
Create a new 32-bit DWORD Value called InactivityTimeoutSecs and give it a value between 0 or 599940 – again, that is the number of seconds of inactivity you want to pass before locking your system.
(2)When signing out from a user session, it seems that no registry involvement will take place.